# angularjs d3.js and dynamic template compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js

I'm working with a library that uses d3 to render a graph.  For simplicity i've just used d3 in this sample below.

This sample sets up click events for svg elements and 2 way data bindings that re-render the SVG.  It also attempts to use svg foreignobject to include html which is nice because I can then use html templates (i'm not a svg guru).

I'm struggling to understand the best way to get events working between the two libraries.  I've tried to figure out how to compile template code with ng- directives, however none of the examples I've read are using svg and it is unclear how angular deals with templates inserted from outside.  I can use the same approach to event propegation as I do in the d3 on 'click' listener for a standard html onclick= element, but it feels like a bit of a hack.

Below is the d3 update that get's recreated when my $scope.data changes.  The ng-click does not seem to get compiled.  I've also looked at $interpolate but it only interpolates varriables and does not process elements.

```
svg.selectAll('foreignObject').data(data.nodes).enter()
    .append('foreignObject')
    .attr("width", 250)
    .attr("height",40)
    .attr("x", 250)
    .attr("y",function(node, index){return index * rh + rp;})
    .style("font", "14px 'Helvetica Neue'")
    .html(function(node){
        var html = '<div style="background: lightgrey"><a href=# onclick="myClick('+node.id+')"> my click</a>FOOOO<a href="#" ng-click="doClick()">ng-click</a>'+node.label+'</div>';

        var compiled = $compile(html)(scope);
        element.append(compiled);
        return html; 
    })
```

My question is: do i just use onclick, or should i continue to try to figure out how to get $compile to work?

Full example

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogPxrV